# Доступ к элементам Dropdown-menu

Tags: bootstrap

У меня есть Navbar со встроенным в него Dropdown-menu, я хотел поменять цвет ссылок в момент когда меню выпадает но мы еще на них не навели, вот код меню:

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-11  menu_nav">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <div class="dropdown pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn_menu btn-block" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
          Dropdown
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li><a href="#">Team 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Team 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Team 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 icons">
      <img src="img/icons_nav.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css стили:

```
.menu_nav{
top: 15px;
right: 150px;
}
.icons{
top: 25px;
left: 150px;
}
.btn_menu{
background: transparent;
border: none;
border-radius: 0px;
color: white;
}

.btn_menu:hover{
border-radius: 0px;
color: aqua;
background: transparent;
 }
.nav-tabs .dropdown-menu, .nav-pills .dropdown-menu, .navbar .dropdown-menu      

{
margin-top: 0px;
border:none;
} /*смещение выпадающего списка*/

.btn-default:active:hover,
.btn-default.active:hover,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:active:focus,
.btn-default.active:focus,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default:focus,
.btn-default:active.focus,
.btn-default.active.focus,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default.focus {
 color: White;
 background-color: #3B3A40;
 border-color: #8c8c8c;
 position: inherit;
 margin-top: 0;
 }/*Стиль кнопки при открытом меню*/
```

вот этим стилем я пытаюсь получить доступ к цвету шрифта выпадающего списка:

```
 .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > ul > li > a:active{
 color: white;
 background-color: transparent;
 }
```

белый цвет появляется только при наведении на пункт меню:

[при открытой кнопке](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFdTv.png),
[при наведении](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzk9L.png).

Comment: А в чем собственно состоит ваш вопрос?

Comment: я хотел поменять цвет ссылок в момент когда меню выпадает но мы еще на них не навели......вот этим стилем я пытаюсь получить доступ к цвету шрифта выпадающего списка.
 Вообще вопрос в синтаксисе доступа к элементу, вроде всё правильно написал, но ссылочки не становятся белыми

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для простоты любому элементу обрамляющему ссылки добавьте id например "mymenu" и стиль что-то вроде:

```
#mymenu a {
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
}
#mymenu a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}
```

тогда не придется ломать голову при изменении структуры меню и остальных элементов

Answer (score 1):

Хорошо бы увидеть пример кода на https://jsfiddle.net/
Но похоже, что этот путь неправильный: 
`.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > ul > li > a:active{}`
пробелы говорят о вложенности, если все эти классы относятся к одному блоку, то нужно убрать проблемы между ними `.navbar-inverse.navbar-nav.open.dropdown-menu > ul > li > a:active{}`